# "PTHREAD_RWLOCK_INITIALIZER undeclared" error in buiding RTEMS

Tags: c, cross-platform, posix, configure, rtems

The error occured in buiding RTEMS-4.11 and used configure param "--enable-posix"
in the source file "posix/src/prwlockinit.c"

```
if ( *rwlock == PTHREAD_RWLOCK_INITIALIZER ) {
  eno = pthread_rwlock_init( rwlock, NULL );
} else {
  eno = 0;
}
```

the log shows "cpukit/posix/src/prwlockinit.c:42:19: error: 'PTHREAD_RWLOCK_INITIALIZER' undeclared (first use in this function)"

when i used shell command: grep -r "PTHREAD_RWLOCK_INITIALIZER" in the rtems source diractory, i got nothing about this macro declared.

how can i fix this problem with "--enable-posix" not "--disable-posix" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an up-to-date compiler. The problem is the libc (newlib) that is compiled in your gcc is outdated. The PTHREAD_RWLOCK_INITIALIZER was added in Jan 2013.

Your best bet is to use the [RTEMS Source Builder](https://ftp.rtems.org/pub/rtems/people/chrisj/source-builder/source-builder.html) to create the most recent compiler for whichever version of RTEMS you use. For the 'master' branch of RTEMS currently, that would be version 4.11.

Comment: P.S. for more timely answers, you may like to consider asking on the RTEMS Users Mailing List.